# Solving a pair of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Lets say I have two ODE's

1) $w'(t)=-\lambda w(t)$

2) $-y''(x)=\lambda y(x)$

Why is the solution to ODE 1) $w(t)=c_1 e^{-\lambda t}$?

Why is the solution to ODE 2) $y(x) = c_2 cos(\lambda x)^\frac{1}{2} + c_3 sin(\lambda x)^\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Do you know separation of variables for (1)?

Comment: I know how to do seperation of variables to get to 1

Comment: Are you sure $(2)$ is not meant to have $y$ instead of $x$ on the RHS?

Comment: Yes so how do I get these solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1)$: $$ \frac{dw}{w} = -\lambda dt$$ Now integrate both sides.

For $(2)$:

If we plug in $e^{rx}$ we get $$e^{rx}(r^2+\lambda ) = 0 \Rightarrow r = \pm \sqrt{\lambda} i$$ So we have two solution namely $$y(x) = e^{\pm(\lambda i) x}$$ So the general solution is $$y(x) = c_1 e^{(\lambda i) x}+c_2 e^{-(\lambda i) x} = c_1\cos{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+c_2\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$